# Incorrect MySQL query string

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a certain result set with MySQL and I am not sure how to pull it off.  I want *everything* from the `call_logs` table for the latest entry by `timestamp` of every `calls_id`. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT distinct calls_id FROM call_logs order by timestamp
```

That gives me only the `calls_id`, though. When I put the following:

```
SELECT distinct calls_id, created, modified, viewed FROM call_logs order by timestamp
```

It returns all of the entries instead of only the last one of each `calls_id`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to get the max timestamp per id.  Then join back to the original table:

```
select cl.*
from call_logs cl join
     (select calls_id, max(timestamp) as maxts
      from call_logs
      group by calls_id
     ) ct
     on cl.calls_id = ct.calls_id and cl.timestamp = ct.maxts
```

Comment: This pulled every record still.

Comment: @user3211035 that seems unlikely

Comment: as unlikely as it seems, that's exactly what it's doing.  Pulls every record.

Comment: @user3211305 . . . This would only return every `calls_id` if there were never any duplicates *or* if all the records for any given `calls_id` had exactly the same timestamp.  Those seem unlikely based on your question.

Answer (score 0):

$query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM call_logs ORDER BY timestamp DESC) AS t1 GROUP BY calls_id";

Answer (score -1):

```
$query="select * from  call_logs group by calls_id order by timestamp"
```

Comment: This pulls only one record, but it isn't the most recent one if I order by timestamp asc or desc.  It still pulls the same record....the first one for each

Comment: if you are using Mysql try **order by max(timestamp) desc**